# How to detect Command/alt/control/fn keys in GLUT

Tags: macos, opengl, keyboard, glut

I'm detecting key pressing and have some problem with the detection with fn(function), ctrl(control), alt and fn(function).

I can detect space bar, enter, ESC, letters, numbers and the cursors. But i can't detect the special keys I tell before. Both method doesn't show anything on screen when I press these keys.

*Method to detect normal keys*

```
void KeyboardFunc(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
    int numeros;

    Key[key] = true;

    cout << "-----------------" << endl;
    cout << "PULSE " << (int) key << endl;
    cout << "-----------------" << endl;

    if(key >= 48 && key < 58)
    {
        numeros = key; 
        key = 'a';  
    }

    switch ( key ) 
    {
        case ' ':   // Space bar
            cout << "Barra Espaciadora pulsada." << endl;
            break;
        case 13:    // #13 es Enter
            cout << "Enter pulsada." << endl;
            break;   
        case 27:    // "27" is the Escape key
            cout << "Tecla ESC pulsada." << endl;
            exit(1);
        case 'a':   // Teclado numérico.
            cout << "Número pulsado: " << numeros - 48 << endl;
            key = numeros;    
    }
}
```

*Method to detect special keys:*

```
void SpecialFunc(int key, int x, int y)
{
    Arrow[key] = true;

    cout << "-----------------" << endl;
    cout << "ESPECIAL PULSADO: " << (int) key << endl;
    cout << "-----------------" << endl;

    switch ( key ) 
    {
        case GLUT_KEY_UP:    // #73 es cursor arriba
            cout << "Cursor ARRIBA pulsada." << endl;
            break;
        case GLUT_KEY_DOWN:    // #81 es cursor abajo
            cout << "Cursor ABAJO pulsada." << endl;
            break;
        case GLUT_KEY_LEFT:    // #73 es cursor izquierda
            cout << "Cursor IZQUIERDA pulsada." << endl;
            break;
        case GLUT_KEY_RIGHT:    // #81 es cursor derecha
            cout << "Cursor DERECHA pulsada." << endl;
            break;    
        case 30:    // #30 es alt_a     
            cout << "Tecla ALT pulsada." << endl;
            break;    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could switch to SDL - get a source for brutalchess,

http://brutalchess.sourceforge.net/

and see how keys are handled in it. datenwolf is right, opengl has nothing to do with input ( mouse, keys, window focus etc. ). You could also try SFML, it's simpler than SDL

http://rastergrid.com/blog/downloads/mountains-demo/

SDL is more flexible than SFML, e.g. KEY_PRESS is something different than KEY_RELEASE.

Answer (score 4):

OpenGL does not deal with user input. It's a drawing API and only covers getting points, lines and triangles into a raster pixmap buffer.

What you are using right now is *GLUT*, a rather simple framework for small OpenGL demos. *GLUT is not part of OpenGL!* If GLUT no longer meets your demands it's time to go on using a more capable framework, or doing all the windowing and input processing from scratch.

Comment: Yeah I use GLUT, i miss to mention this on my original message. I will use SDL to do my job. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so this post is old I know but I just happened to find it while looking for something else.

Answering anyway since it may help other people in the future.

GLUT actually supports the events of ALT... being pressed.

> GLUT_ACTIVE_SHIFT – Set if either you press the SHIFT key, or Caps Lock is on. Note that if they are both on then the constant is not set.
>
> GLUT_ACTIVE_CTRL – Set if you press the CTRL key.
>
> GLUT_ACTIVE_ALT – Set if you press the ALT key.

All you have to do is:

```
void processNormalKeys(unsigned char key, int x, int y) {

if (key == 27)
    exit(0);
else if (key=='r') {
    int mod = glutGetModifiers();
    if (mod == GLUT_ACTIVE_ALT)
        //piece of code
    else if(//...)
        //piece of code
}}
```